# Google Hangouts through a Instant Messaging Client

Tags: debian, pidgin, instant-messaging, google-hangouts, empathy

Is there any way I can set up a Instant Messaging client like Pidgin or Empathy (or any others) on Debian Linux to interface with my Google Hangouts account?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this isn't possible as there isn't a way for third-party apps to interface with Hangouts. Google Chat used XMPP but Hangouts does not. Perhaps someone can prove me wrong...

Answer (score 1):

The [Purple Hangouts](https://bitbucket.org/EionRobb/purple-hangouts/wiki/Home) plugin adds Hangouts support to Pidgin, and is available for Debian (among other OSes).